# "Measure Type Dimensions" in "Accumulating Snapshot" fact table

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

I have an *accumulating snapshot fact* table that tracks the *entry and exit of containers in a terminal*.

The containers can enter and exit in *3 different ways*, so I thought to create a specific dimension table that lists these 3 possible ways (*train, vessel or truck*).

Then I read [this article](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/measure-type-dimension/) which basically says that this technique is wrong, but I can't understand why.

**First article:**

> *Sometimes when a fact table has a long list of facts that is sparsely populated in any individual row, it is tempting to create a measure
> type dimension that collapses the fact table row down to a single
> generic fact identiﬁed by the measure type dimension. We generally do
> not recommend this approach. Although it removes all the empty fact
> columns, it multiplies the size of the fact table by the average
> number of occupied columns in each row, and it makes intra-column
> computations much more difficult. This technique is acceptable when
> the number of potential facts is extreme (in the hundreds), but less
> than a handful would be applicable to any given fact table row.*

I understand that if a "*Measure Type Dimension*" is implemented for a transaction fact table it can create problems like [this other article](https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/normalising-a-fact-table/) says, but I can't see any downside if used for an *accumulating snapshot fact*.

**Second article:** *(some downsides of implementing a "Measure Type Dimension")*

> 1. [...] If we go with a "Measure Type Dimension" we will lose this analytic ability. If one measure is not compatible with the other
>    measures, we can’t add them up.
> 2. [...] The more number of passes our SQL need to run to produce a report, the slower the report.
> 3. [...] On the BI tool, if you don’t put the measure type filter, you are risking the user getting “rubbish information”. From usability
>    point of view, this design is a rubbish.

## Response to Mark Storey-Smith's answer

Very nice approach, i would have never thought about that.

Another thing: every entry and exit of a vehicle that brings container into the terminal has a unique ID which gives me other informations like: expected arrival of the vehicle, actual arrive, if it's a vessel the dock, if it's a truck the tollbooth and many other informations...

These are 3 different fact tables and they must be linked somehow to the container fact table.

I thought that the ID of the voyage is a `degenerate dimension`, so it would directly go into the container fact table. So, my doubt is: should i add 6 different fields in the container fact table (vessel_voyage_in_key, vessel_voyage_out_key, train_voyage_in_key, train_voyage_out_key, truck_voyage_in_key, truck_voyage_out_key) or just 2 other fields (voyage_in, voyage_out) that dynamically links to the various voyage tables?

I hope my doubt is clear, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the guidance is referring to a wide fact table where the majority of measure values are null:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SparseFact
(
    Dim1Key     INT NOT NULL
    , Dim2Key   INT NOT NULL
    , Dim3Key   INT NOT NULL
    , Dim4Key   INT NOT NULL
    , Dim5Key   INT NOT NULL
    , Value1    INT NULL
    , Value2    INT NULL
    , Value3    INT NULL
    , Value4    INT NULL
    , Value5    INT NULL
    , Value6    INT NULL
    , Value7    INT NULL
    , Value8    INT NULL
    ..
    , Value101  INT NULL
    , Value102  INT NULL
    , Value103  INT NULL
);
```

The suggestion is that some people will see all the nulls and decide to do this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DontDoThisFact
(
    Dim1Key             INT NOT NULL
    , Dim2Key           INT NOT NULL
    , Dim3Key           INT NOT NULL
    , Dim4Key           INT NOT NULL
    , Dim5Key           INT NOT NULL
    , MeasureTypeKey    INT NOT NULL
    , Value             INT NOT NULL
);
```

Not good.

In your scenario I think I'd be looking at something like this, which is very different to the scenario described in the articles you referenced.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.InventoryFact
(
    ContainerKey        INT NOT NULL
    , TransportTypeKey  TINYINT NOT NULL
    , EntryDateTime     DATETIME NULL
    , ExitDateTime      DATETIME NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.TransportType
(
    TransportTypeKey    TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , EntryTransport    CHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , ExitTransport     CHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT
    dbo.TransportType
SELECT
    EntryTransport
    , ExitTransport
FROM
    (
    SELECT EntryTransport = 'Train'
    UNION
    SELECT EntryTransport = 'Truck'
    UNION
    SELECT EntryTransport = 'Vessel'
    UNION
    SELECT EntryTransport = 'N/A'
    UNION
    SELECT EntryTransport = 'Unknown'
    ) en
CROSS JOIN
    (
    SELECT ExitTransport = 'Train'
    UNION
    SELECT ExitTransport = 'Truck'
    UNION
    SELECT ExitTransport = 'Vessel'
    UNION
    SELECT ExitTransport = 'N/A'
    UNION
    SELECT ExitTransport = 'Unknown'
    ) ex;
```

To the additional questions...

I would add `ExpectedEntryDate`, `ExpectedExitDate` to the `Container/InventoryFact`. Less certain, without visibility of all the data elements, I would probably put `EntryVoyageId` and `ExitVoyageId` in a separate junk dimension together as one row along with any other degenerate data items (identifiers for the truck, train etc).

I would add 3 new dimensions for `VesselVoyage`, `TruckVoyage` and `TrainVoyage` and 6 Voyage keys (inbound/outbound) to this one fact (it's 6 new keys, not 6 additional rows). You then have the option of placing `Dock` and `Tollbooth` in the appropriate Voyage dimension. If you keep the generic data in these dimensions (`VesselFlag`, `TruckCapacity`) and the specific in a junk dimension (`VesselName`, `VesselMMSI`) they won't explode in size.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for this answer. 

This gives me another doubt that i couldn't fit in the comments here. I have updated my question.. could please check it? Thank you so much, i already have checked your answer as the good one!